I cannot MongoDB repository
I need to istall the last version of MongoDB 7.0
Hello everyone, i need to install the last version of MongoDb 7.
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-7.0.list

But when i try to update:
sudo apt-get update

The linux terminal give me this error:
sudo apt-get update Hit:1 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease Hit:2 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease               Hit:3 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease             Ign:4 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 InRelease Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease Ign:6 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/8.0 InRelease Get:7 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 Release [2,090 B] Err:8 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/8.0 Release   404  Not Found [IP: 52.84.45.6 443] Get:9 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 Release.gpg [866 B] Ign:9 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 Release.gpg Reading package lists... Done E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/8.0 Release' does not have a Release file. N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. W: GPG error: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 160D26BB1785BA38 E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 Release' is not signed. N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Now i'm using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
Any solution?

Related duplicates: 1. Can't install mongodb for ubuntu. 2. Unable to install MongoDB 7.0 on Ubuntu 22.04. 3. MongoDB GPG - Invalid Signatures.
